# Draw Text in firemonkey

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe3

How I can Draw Bitmap high quality text in firemonkey application?

I have an `TImage` in my form with `imgStory` name.

I tried this code but it does not worked and imgStory still show blank!

```
imgStory.Canvas.Stroke.Kind := TBrushKind.bkSolid;
imgStory.Canvas.StrokeThickness := 1;
imgStory.Canvas.Fill.Color := TAlphaColors.Red;
mRect.Create(100, 229, 300, 250);
imgStory.Canvas.FillText(mRect, 'Hello Text!', false, 100, [TFillTextFlag.ftRightToLeft],
TTextAlign.taCenter, TTextAlign.taCenter);
```

Comment: High quality text in fmx? Not something that fmx is renowned for.......

Comment: But when I use text in my language (Persian) the characters shows in bad quality!!

Comment: Yes, fmx is well know for its poor quality text

Answer (score 3):

So its a Timage that requires loading or creating a bitmap first and then drawing on the bitmap. You also need the beginscene and endscene around the drawing commands. To create the bitmap from a file:

```
imgstory.bitmap.createfromfile(filename);
```

or you can create a blank one:

```
imgstory.bitmap.create(width,height);
```

Then the drawing becomes:

```
imgstory.Bitmap.canvas.BeginScene();
imgStory.Bitmap.canvas.Stroke.Kind := TBrushKind.bkSolid;
imgStory.Bitmap.canvas.StrokeThickness := 1;
imgStory.bitmap.Canvas.Fill.Color := TAlphaColors.Red;
mRect.Create(100, 229, 300, 250);
imgStory.bitmap.Canvas.FillText(mRect, 'Hello Text!', false, 100, [TFillTextFlag.ftRightToLeft],
TTextAlign.taCenter, TTextAlign.taCenter);
imgstory.bitmap.Canvas.endscene
```

Comment: FillText doesn't use stroke properties. It only uses fill properties of the canvas. And the resulting text looks dismal at best.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old questions, but I came across it, and got it working on my end.  Here is my code.  I think maybe it was the way you were setting up mrect.  I don't think just calling the .create() function without setting the output to a variable will work.

```
Image1.Bitmap.canvas.Stroke.Kind := TBrushKind.bkSolid;
Image1.Bitmap.canvas.StrokeThickness := 1;
Image1.bitmap.Canvas.Fill.Color := TAlphaColors.Red;
Image1.Bitmap.Canvas.Font.Size:=36;
Image1.Bitmap.Canvas.Font.Family:='Arial';
Image1.Bitmap.Canvas.Font.Style:=[TFontStyle.fsbold];
ARect := TRectF.Create(100, 229, 400, 270);
Image1.Bitmap.Canvas.BeginScene;
Image1.Bitmap.Canvas.FillText(ARect, 'Hello Text!', false, 100, [], TTextAlign.taCenter);
Image1.Bitmap.Canvas.EndScene;
```

Comment: StrokeThickness is now Stroke.Thickness in newer versions of FMX.

Comment: Thanks!  It's been a minute since I thought about this... @rhody

Answer (score 0):

When you are drawing on a canvas other than in a paint method, you need to surround the drawing commands with beginscene and endscene.

So add a line before your code:

```
imgStory.canvas.beginscene;
```

and after your code:

```
imgStory.canvas.endscene;
```

Comment: Sorry, missed the bit about it being a Timage and not a bitmap. You need to either load an image into the Timage or create a blank one. Then draw on imgstory.bitmap.canvas. Will post a new answer as I can't work out how to format code in this comment.